# Get the full path of selected file

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get the full path of the located file. I am searching directories and when the file is found, I need to get its path. I have all the code to search and I just need it to set a string or get the path of the file. How can I do that?

```
Dim substring As String = strJobNumber.Substring(0, 2)
Dim directory As String
Dim strFileName As String = "rptWESSSummary " & strJobNumber & "-" & strLineNumber & "-r1.xlsx"

If substring = "13" Then
    directory = "W:\CUSTOM\130000\" & strJobNumber
    For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        fName = IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)
        If fName = strFileName Then
            ' This is where I need the path of the file if it’s found.
            MsgBox("File found!!!!!!!!!")
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new `DirectoryInfo` for the directory; it’ll give you [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) objects:

```
For Each file In New IO.DirectoryInfo(directory).GetFiles("*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    If file.Name = strFileName Then ' Please don’t use Hungarian notation
        MessageBox.Show("File found!")
        ' Do something with file.FullName
    End If
Next
```

If `Name` is really the only check you’re doing, though, why not search for it in the first place?

```
Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo("W:\CUSTOM\130000\" & strJobNumber)

For Each file In directory.GetFiles(strFileName, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    ' Do something with file.FullName
Next
```

Comment: For some reason its not letting me use file.Fullpath 'system.IO.Filesysteminfo.fullpath' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Protected"

Comment: I’m not sure how you got a `FileSystemInfo` object. Could you show your modified code, please?

Comment: `        Dim substring As String = strJobNumber.Substring(0, 2)
        Dim strFileName As String = "rptWESSSummary " & strJobNumber & "-" & strLineNumber & "-r1.xlsx"
        Dim test As String

        If substring = "13" Then
            Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo("W:\CUSTOM\130000\" & strJobNumber)

            For Each file In directory.GetFiles(strFileName, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                test = file.Fullpath

            Next`

Comment: What I have it doing is I dont know the full directories because there is a bunch of sub folders and i have it searching them for the file then i need the locaton of that file to be a string so i can then use it in my other code.

Comment: Try using `file.FullName` instead